# Problem getting JavaDoc to resolve Java 6

Tags: ant, javadoc, task

I'm having problems getting Ant to relatively refer to Java 6 API in my javaDoc task. Instead of having, say "File", I am getitng the whole package reference first. It is very annoying!

Here is my code. Could anyone advise?

```
 <javadoc sourcepath="${src.dir}"
        destdir="${packaging.dir}/docs/javadoc"
        packagenames="org.*"
        link="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/"
        doctitle="my API Documentation"
        bottom="my API Documentation - Copyright 2010 to me. All Rights Reserved."
      />
```

I would also like to add link information for log4j and also hibernate. Is it a simple case of adding more link rows?

Thanks. Ben.

Answer (score 0):

To process multiple external links, use nested `link` elements of the Ant [`javadoc`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) task.  Something like:

```
<javadoc sourcepath="${src.dir}"
         destdir="${packaging.dir}/docs/javadoc"
         packagenames="org.*"
         doctitle="my API Docs"
         bottom="my API Docs - Copyright 2010 to me. All Rights Reserved.">
    <link href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/" />
    <link href="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/" />
    <link href="http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/"/>
</javadoc>
```